# boostrap modal causes shift of background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, background, modal-dialog

I'm new to bootstrap and I found a modal bug: when I press a modal button, the background goes right of 15px about. My bootstrap template is 3.3.0 version.

I tried to upgrade to last 3.3.4 version, but it doesn't work for me.
I replaced:

- 3.3.4 bootstrap.css file to 3.3.0 bootstrap.css file,
- 3.3.4 bootstrap.min.css file to 3.3.0 bootstrap.min.css file,
- 3.3.4 bootstrap.js file to 3.3.0 bootstrap.js file,
- 3.3.4 bootstrap.min.js file to 3.3.0 bootstrap.min.js file,
- 3.3.4 modal.js file to 3.3.0 modal.js file.

Please, can you tell me what files I have to modify and what parameters I have to change?

Thank you in advance to all!
Gianfranco

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually because in bootstrap 3.3.4 there are some updated version in modal plugin.You can read here http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/03/16/bootstrap-3-3-4-released/

Comment: Hello, manually, I replaced all common files from 3.3.4 version (I downloaded the last version 3.3.4) to 3.3.0 version of my template. But it still doesn't work. What I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you uploaded somewhere?? Then i can tell you properly what the issue.

Comment: My website is online here: http://www.oltrecalcio.com/vetreria9/it/ look at the bottom and presso on "Italia" button. Thanks!

Comment: Dear friend, I discovered that the shift regards only the navbar!! So I have to edit something on navbar....thank you for your help!